Opening Jupyter notebooks automatically when double clicking on (windows) desktop
I hope I didn't overlook something, but I could not find on StackOverflow how I can get Jupyter to run and open ipynb files when I double-click on them on the Windows desktop.
I installed Anaconda and of course I could open Anaconda, then Jupyter Notebook, and then open the file. But I'd like to just double-click and go.
Any pointers?
Thanks a lot!
